# NoMethodError in Rails method using has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models, has-one

Here is my code:

// in swimmer.rb (model):

```
    belongs_to :user
```

// in user.rb (model):

```
    has_one :swimmer, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :swimmer, :allow_destroy => true   
    attr_accessible :swimmer_attributes
```

// in swimmers_controller.rb:

```
  def profile
    @swimmer = Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user)
    @swimmer_nickname = @swimmer.nickname
    @swimmer_gender = @swimmer.gender
    @title = "Swimmer Profile for #{@current_user.email}"
  end
```

// in profile.html.erb (in swimmers views folder)

```
   <% if @swimmer %>
     <h3><%= @title %></h3>
     <p>Nickname: <%= @swimmer_nickname %></p>
     <p>Gender: <%= @swimmer_gender %></p>
   <% else %>
     <h3>No Swimmer Profile for<%= current_user.email %></h3>
   <% end %>
```

If a swimmer object has a user_id that matches the @swimmer instance variable in the swimmers#controller method, because there is a logged in user (using the Devise gem) and a swimmer has been created for that user, then the profile view works as intended. If not, the page shows an error:

```
   NoMethodError (undefined method `nickname' for nil:NilClass):
     app/controllers/swimmers_controller.rb:66:in `profile'
```

But since the profile view has an if/else conditional, I want the lack of the swimmer object associated with the logged in user to force the view to show the else content. Apparently, the "Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user)" method is creating a nil object in the NilClass. How do I get it so that it doesn't create anything and thereby brings up the else conditional?

Repo is at https://github.com/drollwit/vst2/tree/ver2. This is an exercise, not a real project. There is probably an easy answer here but I can't figure it out (still learning Rails basics). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of error exists in the below line of code.

```
@swimmer = Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user)
```

It never finds Swimmer based on user_id.Because

```
find_by_user_id
```

expects an ID.Try

```
@swimmer = Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

You will get swimmer object then the error will not occur.

And you view file can be improved by

```
<% if @swimmer %>
 <h3><%= "Swimmer Profile for #{@current_user.email}" %></h3>
 <p>Nickname: <%= @swimmer.nickname %></p>
 <p>Gender: <%= @swimmer.gender %></p>
<% else %>
 <h3>No Swimmer Profile for<%= current_user.email %></h3>
<% end %>
```

This will reduce below lines of code from controller.

```
@swimmer_nickname = @swimmer.nickname
@swimmer_gender = @swimmer.gender
@title = "Swimmer Profile for #{@current_user.email}"
```

Comment: Perfect. That avoids using #try in the view and makes the controller cleaner. I figured there had to be something obvious I was missing. I guess the larger takeaway is to learn how to use these find_by dynamic methods correctly.

Comment: It seems like this answered you question and should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the view, it's your profile method:

```
def profile
  @swimmer = Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  @swimmer_nickname = @swimmer.nickname
  @swimmer_gender = @swimmer.gender
  @title = "Swimmer Profile for #{@current_user.email}"
end
```

If no swimmer can be found then @swimmer is nil and the following line fails because you are invoking the method 'nickname' on nil.

A simple fix is as follows:

```
def profile
  @swimmer = Swimmer.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  @swimmer_nickname = @swimmer.try(:nickname)
  @swimmer_gender = @swimmer.try(:gender)
  @title = "Swimmer Profile for #{@current_user.email}"
end
```

Now @simmwer_nickname and @swimmer_gender will be set to nil if @swimmer doesn't exist. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try.

Personally, I wouldn't assign these extra instance variables in the controller like this. I would move this to the view or perhaps a helper.

Comment: That worked - thanks! I figured it was a method (not a view) problem. I'll take a closer look at how the try method works. As for moving all this to a helper method, you're right - its not a "skinny controller." I fiddled with it a bit and moved it into the view, but it looks like too much Ruby there. I need to look into how to make it a helper method.